# Missing resource name in Code::Blocks and therefore FindResource doesn't work

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

I have a project in Code::Blocks.
In my resource.rc file I have

```
#ifndef IDC_STATIC
#define IDC_STATIC (-1)
#endif

#define TWEETY                                  102
```

In my resource.h file I have

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <richedit.h>
#include "resource.h"

TWEETY IMAGE "Tweety.png"
```

I build the project and afterwards open the exe file in ResEdit.
This is what I see there.
[ResEdit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49grL.png)

There are no resource names, only resource ids.
This has a consequence (at least it's my conclusion) that I cannot find the image resource using FindResource function.

```
// Loads the PNG containing the splash image into a HBITMAP.
HBITMAP LoadSplashImage()
{
    HBITMAP hbmpSplash = NULL;

    // load the PNG image data into a stream
    IStream * ipImageStream = CreateStreamOnResource(MAKEINTRESOURCE(TWEETY), _T("PNG"));
    if (ipImageStream == NULL)
        goto Return;

    // load the bitmap with WIC
    IWICBitmapSource * ipBitmap = LoadBitmapFromStream(ipImageStream);
    if (ipBitmap == NULL)
        goto ReleaseStream;

    // create a HBITMAP containing the image
    hbmpSplash = CreateHBITMAP(ipBitmap);
    ipBitmap->Release();

    ReleaseStream:
       ipImageStream->Release();
    Return:
       return hbmpSplash;
}

// Creates a stream object initialized with the data from an executable resource.
IStream * CreateStreamOnResource(LPCTSTR lpName, LPCTSTR lpType)
{
    // initialize return value
    IStream * ipStream = NULL;

    // find the resource
    HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(NULL, lpName, lpType);

    if (hrsrc == NULL)
        goto Return;

    // load the resource
    DWORD dwResourceSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hrsrc);
    HGLOBAL hglbImage = LoadResource(NULL, hrsrc);
    if (hglbImage == NULL)
        goto Return;

    // lock the resource, getting a pointer to its data
    LPVOID pvSourceResourceData = LockResource(hglbImage);
    if (pvSourceResourceData == NULL)
        goto Return;

    // allocate memory to hold the resource data
    HGLOBAL hgblResourceData = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, dwResourceSize);
    if (hgblResourceData == NULL)
        goto Return;

    // get a pointer to the allocated memory
    LPVOID pvResourceData = GlobalLock(hgblResourceData);
    if (pvResourceData == NULL)
        goto FreeData;

    // copy the data from the resource to the new memory block
    CopyMemory(pvResourceData, pvSourceResourceData, dwResourceSize);
    GlobalUnlock(hgblResourceData);

    // create a stream on the HGLOBAL containing the data
    if (SUCCEEDED(CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hgblResourceData, TRUE, &ipStream)))
        goto Return;

    FreeData:
    // couldn't create stream; free the memory

    GlobalFree(hgblResourceData);

    Return:

    return ipStream;
}
```

Please advise what I'm doing wrong.

**Update - it is working now.**

```
TWEETY IMAGE "Tweety.png"

IStream * ipImageStream = CreateStreamOnResource(MAKEINTRESOURCE(TWEETY), _T("IMAGE"));

HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(NULL, lpName, lpType);
```

However, in ResEdit I still don't see the resource name, only resource id.[image: ResEdit - no resource name]

And this:
MAKEINTRESOURCE(TWEETY);

returns "error - cannot access memory at address 0x66".

Comment: _"...The name of the resource. Alternately, rather than a pointer, this parameter can be __MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID), where ID is the integer identifier of the resource__. For more information, see the Remarks section below...._" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-findresourcea  The resource compiler should put these IDs as `#define`s into `"resource.h"` for you.

Comment: ' _T("PNG") ` does not match resource type "IMAGE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource types are identified by ID or name. Your resource script defines a resource type with name `IMAGE` (that's why you see `"IMAGE"` in ResEdit; note the quotation marks).

You are passing a resource type with name `PNG` to the call to [FindResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-findresourcea). The module doesn't have a resource type named `PNG`. It contains a resource type named `IMAGE`. When you pass `_T("IMAGE")` your code starts to work.

Comment: Thank you - it works now. The resource is found
FindResource(NULL, lpName, lpType);

Comment: However, I'm surprised that FIndResource actually works. The image resource has no name and MAKEINTRESOURCE(TWEETY) returns "error - cannot access memory at address 0x66".

Comment: `MAKEINTRESOURCE(TWEETY)` is an expression. It doesn't execute, and doesn't attempt to access memory. It's not clear to me *who* is returning this error. It's probably your IDE or debugger, that doesn't understand the semantics of this particular string type, and overloaded *"ID or name"* value masked as a string.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It looks like both ResEdit and Code::Blocks Watch debugging window provide misleading information about resource names. Thank you.

Comment: ResEdit shows accurate resource information, just as you specified it.